# Different number of users in wordpress users window and phpmyadmin mysql wp_users table

Tags: wordpress

I am seeing different number of users on my wordpress in Users shows 1189 users also on site the members it shows are 1189 but when i go to phpmyadmin it shows me only 853 users.

Steps I have applied:-

First I thought the problem was with the wp_usermeta --> meta_value of wp_capabilities I have changed the value a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1,"1";} but nothing happens. I am attaching different screenshots to get you guys more idea on this including the wp_usermeta data. Please tell me if something is wrong.

Comment: Please attach the screenshots mentioned in the question.

Comment: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPUqDQ58yfTM3FGG2SNQQvIKPYDyyihIWNeSJe0ix777b7SaMmLtUUCX15QciPj8Q?key=MlNXSmQzc01hVU5sakpWV3RsOGxJZG5YWGQxQmFB

Comment: Please see from the above links all the screenshots nessecary are there

Comment: Maybe phpmyadmin links to your local server!

Comment: @KhanSaadi I dont know the answer. But Amir has a good point, try checking whether you're really accessing the right DB or if the subscribers data isn't stored somewhere else than wp_users table.

Comment: @amir Can you please tell me how to check this that either my phpmyadmin links to local server or not?

Comment: Go into the WordPress control panel Users page. Change your personal name, or the name of some other user. Use something silly and distinctive, like Khanananan for example. Then use phpmyAdmin to look at the wp_users table. If you find the name changed then phyMyAdmin is connected to the same database as your WordPress instance. If not, it's connected to a different database.

Comment: But i add the 8 user recently with different roles and it is showing in wp_users table does that means that it is connected to correct instance??? I am also checking your thing but just thought to tell you this.?

Comment: I have update the user name and I couldn't see the name changed in the phpmyadmin wp_users table.. Please tell me now how can I correct it to the same instance?